# C# If/else statement not working

Tags: c#, sql

I have an if/else statement that is not working.

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
  string permission = rdr["Permission"].ToString();
  if (permission == "Exec")
  {
     Run my code
  }
  else
  {
     lblErrorStart.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

If Permission does equal Exec then everything works fine but (when stepping through the code) I have noticed that when Permission does not equal Exec, it does not trigger the Else.  It just goes back to the while statement and stops.  Let me know if I need to provide any more code.

Note: I only have Exec in the database.  Everything else is null.

Comment: Try getting rid of the white-space in between the if statement's closing bracket and the else statement?

Comment: @MoarCodePlz: Are you serious?

Comment: Do a rebuild of the entire solution and retest. It could be that the source code is out-of-sync with the binaries.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz: C# is not white space or indent sensitive (there are some exceptions, such as concatenating a string across newlines, but in this case it doesn't matter).

Comment: Are you sure `else` is not triggered? Or could it be that you are doing something already done? If you put `MessageBox.Show("Hello");` in the statement, does it show a messagebox?

Comment: `string permission = rdr["Permission"].ToString();` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `rdr["Permission"]` is null.

Comment: @mihi great catch.  I didn't even think about that.

Comment: As Ed S. mentions below, the control visibility won't change right away, do you have a break point on the code in the `else` to see if it's executing or not?

Comment: mihi, can you put that as the answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: FYI, I added another value into the database and the Label triggered as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have noticed that when Permission does not equal Exec, it does not trigger the Else.

I have a very hard time believing that.  Please show us the exact contents of `permission` when it does not equal `"Exec"`.

Also realize that setting the label to visible will not update as soon as that code is executed.  This is because you are not allowing the [Windows Message Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) to process messages.  So even though the `Visible` property is set to true, a `WM_PAINT` message is never processed (until your loop exits), so the appearance of your control will not change.

EDIT:

As Brian Gideon points out in a comment, your executable version may be out of sync with your code.  Rebuild the entire project and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when testing exact equality, you fail based on what you do NOT see... If your data is from a record set, or other structure and the actual value is NOT trimmed(), it will fail...

"Exec " == "Exec" will fail

Try

string permission = rdr["Permission"].ToString().Trim();

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's an `if` `else` statement like stated:

```
if(label1.Text == "True")
{
    label1.Forecolor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
    label1.Text = "ERROR!";
    label1.Forecolor = Color.Red;
}
```

Also, you can do multiple `if` statements and if none of them are relatively `true` you can have them all lead to the `else` statement.